# C# Saving a form to image without anti aliasing

Tags: c#, antialiasing, image-capture

I am checking if i am able to capture an image and save it to an image file without losing the pixel resolution? I had a 1D barcode inside a form, however i will need to print this form together with the barcode. When i capture and save to a bmp file and print, the barcode is not clear at all.
Even printscreen is anti-aliasing?
The situation is a lot like the thread below except now i need to save it later for printing.

[Undesired anti-aliasing when drawing bitmap on a window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606292/undesired-anti-aliasing-when-drawing-bitmap-on-a-window)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Printscreen does not add anti-aliasing - the problem probably is in the capturing bit. Hard to tell without any code, though.

Comment: Printing a barcode that was made to fit a window never works well.  A printer's resolution is easily x6 better than a monitor.  Inevitably the barcode bar pixels turn into 6x6 blobs, the Graphics.InterpolationMode property tries to do a credible job of it so the blobbiness is not so visible.  Bar code scanners hate that.  Always best to create the barcode when you print it so it is rendered with the printer's resolution.  Or use InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor so you preserve the blobs with sharp edges.